# how to add a item in a list of list using python

Tags: python, list, arraylist

Is there any way to add a item to a list of list using python.

As an example there is a list as below:

```
test_list = [['abc','2'],['cds','333'],['efg']]
```

I want to add a item `'444'` for the position `test_list[2][1]`.

At last list should be:

```
test_list = [['abc','2'],['cds','333'],['efg','444']]
```

Comment: `test_list[2].append(444)` should do it

Comment: Yes It's worked well. Thanks you @Anwarvic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is definitely something you can do.

You simply access the list object that you want to add another item to by its index, and then call [`.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) on that list object with the new value.

```
test_list = [['abc','2'], ['cds','333'], ['efg']]
test_list[2].append('444')
# test_list is now: [['abc','2'], ['cds','333'], ['efg', '444']]
```

Comment: Isn't this now mine

Comment: if you depend on position append always add element at end so when you want to add element at specific position using insert with index

Comment: @ravishankarchavare yes that is correct that `.append()` will add it to the end of the list, however the original question is a bit vague as to whether the item should always be inserted to the `[2][1]` position when another element is already there or if it should just be at the end of the list. I feel that `.append()` matches more use cases for adding an item to a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
test_list = [['abc','2'],['cds','333'],['efg']]
test_list[2].insert(1,"444")
print(test_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `append`, `append` does your job:

```
>>> test_list = [['abc','2'],['cds','333'],['efg']]
>>> test_list[2].append('444')
>>> test_list
[['abc', '2'], ['cds', '333'], ['efg', '444']]
>>>
```

Or use `+=`, that adds stuff together, but two lists, so do:

```
>>> test_list = [['abc','2'],['cds','333'],['efg']]
>>> test_list[2] += ['444']
>>> test_list
[['abc', '2'], ['cds', '333'], ['efg', '444']]
>>>
```

`append` is a builtin python list method, here is the [documentation for it](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), and for `+=`, that is a builtin addition operator, see the [documentation for it](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/operator.html#operator.iadd).

Answer (score 0):

Above Three are absolutely correct. But I want to add One thing If you want to add an element in a list of list and you don't know the ending index you can do something like,

```
>>> test_list = [['abc','2'],['cds','333'],['efg']]
>>> test_list[-1].append('444')
>>> test_list
[['abc', '2'], ['cds', '333'], ['efg', '444']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use cutting to do this:

```
test_list = [['abc', '2'], ['cds', '333'], ['efg']]
test_list[2][1:] = ['444']
print(test_list)
```

> [['abc', '2'], ['cds', '333'], ['efg', '444']]