# Add a random value to all items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
[[[1, 2, 3]], [1, 2, 3], [[2]]]
```

Is there a way to add a random value to all the items without having to do something like this:

```py
from random import randit
[[[list[0][0][0]+randit(0, 10), list[0][0][1]+randit(0, 10), list[0][0][2]+randit(0, 10)]],..
```

Comment: well you can try a `for` loop. or you can generate random list then add the random list and the original

Comment: this [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016000/how-to-add-a-item-in-a-list-of-list-using-python) should help in combination to the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a recursion:

```
from random import randint

def substitute(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, int):
        return lst + randint(1, 10)
    else:
        for i, item in enumerate(lst):
            lst[i] = substitute(item)
        return lst

your_list = [[[1, 2, 3]], [1, 2, 3], [[2]]]

print(your_list)
print(substitute(your_list))
```

outputs:

```
>>>[[[1, 2, 3]], [1, 2, 3], [[2]]]
>>>[[[10, 10, 5]], [11, 9, 7], [[6]]]
```

Can also phrased in one line:

```
from random import randint

def recursion(lst):
    return lst + randint(1, 10) if isinstance(lst, int) else [recursion(item) for item in lst]
```