# How to add an item to a list of lists in Python that has a fixed size

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I am following the approach on [how to add a item in a list of list using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016000/how-to-add-a-item-in-a-list-of-list-using-python)

but it seems not to work when I fix the size of the list of lists

`lst=[[None]]*5`

if I do `lst[0].append([0])`, It updates all the indices of the list

`[[None, [0]], [None, [0]], [None, [0]], [None, [0]], [None, [0]]]`

rather than
 `[[None, [0]], [None], [None], [None], [None]]`

Why so? and how to make sure that only the required index gets updated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list multiplication: \[\[...\]\]\*3 makes 3 lists which mirror each other when modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688223/python-list-multiplication-3-makes-3-lists-which-mirror-each-other-when)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, where the specified index gets updated, you should create separate inner lists for each position in the outer list.

You can do this using a list comprehension:

```
lst = [[None] for _ in range(5)]

lst[0].append([0])
```

it will only update the inner list at index 0, and the other inner lists will remain unaffected:

```
[[None, [0]], [None], [None], [None], [None]]
```

When you create a list like this: `[[None]]*5`, you are actually creating a list that contains five references to the same inner list `[None]`.

This means that when you modify the inner list using `lst[0].append([0])`, it modifies the same inner list object that is referenced in all five positions of your outer list.
[image]